# Win Serv 2008 R2 Standard Exchange Management Console Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, exchange, distribution-lists

When I am in the Exchange Console and under the Recipient Configuration --> Distribution Group some of the DLs are greyed out as shown below:

[image]

The ones in color I can make adjustments to who is in the group while the grey ones I cannot. Why is that and how can I make it so that I can add/remove people from any distribution list that needs to be augmented?

Thanks

Link:

Comment: Is that DL nested within another?  If that's the case, you'd have to start at the "root DL" and then change the groups that are nested inside it.

Comment: I tried to make it a Universal group but I receive an Exchange Error stating... http://tinypic.com/r/2mchkwh/5

Comment: Not sure how to track it down through the groups, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @ZacharyMalone Please *type out* your Exchange error. Pasting pictures is a lousy way to communicate text information, and Google doesn't OCR them for search purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Zachary,

It would appear that your groups are global and not universal groups.  Exchange likes the groups to be Universal in scope so that they are replicated to all the Global Catalogs.  So you should convert all of them to a Universal group scope if possible.

Your error you get when trying to convert one is due to it being nested within another group (check the MemberOf property).

You can get more info from this link, it goes into it in some more detail: http://telnet25.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/a-universal-group-cannot-have-a-local-group-as-a-member/